# How to write an ArrayList of Strings into a text file?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to write an `ArrayList<String>` into a text file.

The `ArrayList` is created with the code:

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
    line, ":Mode set - Out of Service In Service");

while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    arr.add(st.nextToken());    
}
```

Comment: What's your desired output for this input?

Comment: You code looks like it is reading a text file into an array. Is that what you actually mean?

Comment: my code is reading a file and then tokenize it and store those tokens in an arraylist. now i want to write this arraylist into a file.

Comment: The answers all assume a different type of output. Can you give an example of how you want the output to look (or does it just need to be readable?)

Comment: @kathy: I was trying to write this arraylist in a text file. Anyways, I have done that already with the help of Andrey's code. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
...
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt"); 
for(String str: arr) {
  writer.write(str + System.lineSeparator());
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: define your array as: ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: what do you meann by arr?

Comment: it's the name of the variable that holds reference to array

Comment: Where exactly would output.txt be situated in this case? Internal storage? - i.e. how to retrieve this file?

Comment: in current working directory (i.e. directory from which you started your java program)

Answer (score 71):

## Java NIO

You can do that with a single line of code nowadays [using Java NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

Create the arrayList and the `Path` object representing the file where you want to write into:

```
Path out = Paths.get("output.txt");
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<> ( Arrays.asList ( "a" , "b" , "c" ) );
```

Create the actual file, and fill it with the text in the ArrayList by calling on [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) utility class.

```
Files.write(out,arrayList,Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Comment: what is Files, what package is it from?

Comment: java.nio.file.Files, standard Java class since 1.7

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest using FileUtils from Apache Commons IO library.It will create the parent folders of the output file,if they don't exist.while  `Files.write(out,arrayList,Charset.defaultCharset());` will not do this,throwing exception if the parent directories don't exist.

```
FileUtils.writeLines(new File("output.txt"), encoding, list);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to create each ArrayList item in a single line then you can use this code

```
private void createFile(String file, ArrayList<String> arrData)
            throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file + ".txt");
        int size = arrData.size();
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            String str = arrData.get(i).toString();
            writer.write(str);
            if(i < size-1)**//This prevent creating a blank like at the end of the file**
                writer.write("\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    }
```

Comment: What if you open the same file and continue writing to it? I think have the last newline character is useful.

Comment: Yes it will be useful for append mode. Just comment the if condition and will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to serialize the ArrayList object to a file so you can read it back in again later use ObjectOuputStream/ObjectInputStream writeObject()/readObject() since ArrayList implements [Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).  It's not clear to me from your question if you want to do this or just write each individual item.  If so then Andrey's answer will do that.

Comment: I just want to add each item to a file but its showing an error message of incompatible type.

Answer (score 3):

You might use ArrayList overloaded method `toString()`

```
String tmp=arr.toString();
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
pw.println(tmp.substring(1,tmp.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use BufferedWriter :

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("note.txt")));

String stuffToWrite = info;

writer.write(stuffToWrite);

writer.close();
```

and before that remember too add

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
```

Comment: This answer literally has nothing to do with ArrayLists of Strings, which is what the original poster was asking about.

Comment: @Kaiser Keister But all that's needed is to convert the `ArrayLIst` to a `String` which is easy to do in a loop with `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score -1):

[Write a array list to text file using JAVA](https://latestjavafeatures.blogspot.com/2022/12/write-array-list-to-text-file-using-java.html)

```
public void writeFile(List<String> listToWrite,String filePath) {

    try {
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(filePath);
        for (String string : listToWrite) {
            myWriter.write(string);
            myWriter.write("\r\n");
        }
        myWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you affiliated with the site? How is this better or worse than the other answers here?

Answer (score -1):

```
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
    Arrays.asStream(arr.stream()
            .forEach(i -> {
                try{
                        writer.write(i + ",");
                }
                catch (Exception e){}
                        
            }));
    writer.close();
```