# Android Edittext listviews?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have been scouring the Internet for a way to use an input box at the top of the page, and have an add & remove button.

I want the `EditText` to write to the `ListView`, which in turn writes the list to a `.txt`-file.

I have tried breaking this down into multiple small sections of just simple things like

- getting the input from the `EditText` to post to a `TextView`.
- Organizing a `ListView`
- writing to a file and
- reading from a file.

If you have any advice about how to get the `ListView` to go from the `EditText` greatly helpful.

Comment: Have you already reviewed the [ListView Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have an `ArrayList<String>` to store your Strings from the TextView, and in turn have that `ArrayList<String>` feed into the `ListView`. For example, for your Add button handler:

```
// Declare our variables
ArrayList<String> myStringList = new ArrayList<String>();


// OnClickListener stuff for Add button
..
myStringList.add(myEditText.getText().toString());
myListView.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringList));

..
// Close OnClickListener stuff
```

Make sure you refresh your list adapter afterwards to show the new values. Likewise if you're deleting, use `myStringList.remove(index)` to remove that string from the list and refresh the array adapter. As for writing to a text file, have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548157/how-to-write-an-arraylist-into-a-text-file).