# Java writeObject is writing an empty ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having trouble writing an `ArrayList` of a custom class to a file.  I'm using

```
public static void SaveEmployees() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("magicscheduleEmp.sav");
    save.writeObject(employeeList);
    save.close();
}
```

Where `employeeList` is declared and initialized as an `ArrayList` of `Employees` (my class) in the main method.  I have definitely added objects to `employeeList`, but calling `SaveEmployees` writes an empty `ArrayList` to the file.  The `Employee` class is serializable.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: employeeList is initialized here (in the main method)

```
    public static ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and populated through user input (in another jFrame class)

```
    if(MainUI.addempcheck == true){
        Employee newEmployee = new Employee(LastName.getText(), FirstName.getText());
        newEmployee.position = EmpType.getSelectedItem().toString();
        MainUI.employeeList.add(newEmployee);
        MainUI.listModel.addElement(newEmployee.writeName().toString());
    }
    try {
        MainUI.SaveEmployees();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewEmployeeUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewEmployeeUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    this.dispose();
```

I have a button which prints the contents of employeeList, and shows that the list is populated before I save it.  Maybe it's a problem with calling SaveEmployees?

Comment: Show us how `employeeList` is initialized and populated. It must be  a static field in your example.

Comment: Without seeing what is going on with arraylist, I can only recommend you to write each element separately, like shown in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6548204/1276128

Comment: If you're using an `ArrayList` to back your `List<Employee> employeeList` and you're sure your `Employee` class implements `Serializable`, then `employeeList` is empty.

Comment: You will have to give more of your code. I tried out an SSCCE and write and read works fine covering what you have exposed here. Employee class serializable, employeeList as static.

Comment: Are you positive the file is empty? Have you tried deserializing it and printing the results? It seems that nothing is wrong with your code. Maybe you could try using a `BufferedOutputStream` to wrap the `FileOutputStream`.