# Add to file what's not deleted in read file

Tags: java, delete-file

I'm trying to read from one file, add to array and delete it. My concern is, if some records cannot be deleted, I want to save them to another file. Just can't get any idea how to do it :(

```
String deviceGUID;
List<String> listaGuida = new ArrayList<String>();
File file = new File("test.txt");

try {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    deviceGUID = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(deviceGUID);
    listaGuida.add(deviceGUID);
  }
  sc.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Missing file!", e);
}

String[] temp = listaGuida.toArray(new String[0]);
for (String list : temp) {
  try {
    ServiceApi.remove(Long.parseLong(list));
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "All devices deleted!");
  } catch (ServiceApi ex) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to delete device: " + list, ex);
  } finally { 
    ???    
  }
}
```

Guess the code will go in finally block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple:

```
List<String> itemsThatCouldNotBeDeleted = new ArrayList<>();
```

goes somewhere in front of your second try block.

Within the catch block, you call `itemsThatCouldNotBeDeleted.add(whatever)`.

And finally, in your finally block, you check if that list is empty; and if not; you do whatever pleases you with that content.

In other words: if you want to collect elements, then put them into some sort of collection; and later iterate that collection and do whatever you want to do about it.

Writing a list to a file is straight forward as well; and has been documented here many times; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548157/how-to-write-an-arraylist-of-strings-into-a-text-file) for example.

Comment: hehe, that was easy, tnx. I have list now, but how to save those to new file, lets call it failed.txt

Comment: See my updated answer. But please understand: this is not a free service where you drop your requirements and other people explain **everything** to you. It takes **less* time to find the answer to "how do i write a list to a file" with google than it takes to even write up that comment to SO as you just did.