# android - paths.get(fileName); for API level 16

Tags: android, api, path

I want to save a ArrayList in a textfile and read it later again.
My Code is:

```
public static ArrayList readFromFile(String filename){
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            myList.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myList;
}

public static void saveToFile(String fileName, ArrayList list){
    Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName);

    try {
        Files.write(filePath, list, Charset.defaultCharset());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But i got two problems:
1. Paths.get(); is only usable since API level 26
2. i cant test this code because i got an amd pc and there is no emulator for api 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path and Files are quite new classes in Java. 
Try to write to file the old way using OutputStream. There are many tutorials for this, for example https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to write a list to a file using older `java.io.FileWriter` library which works using API Level 16:

```
public static void saveToFile(String fileName, ArrayList<String> list)
 {
   try
   {
     FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
     for (String str: list){
       writer.write(str+"\r\n"); }
     writer.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace(); }
 }
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548157/how-to-write-an-arraylist-of-strings-into-a-text-file) & [`java.io.FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) library for more options and details.