# What is the simplest way to create a new text file with values from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, fileinputstream

- I want the text file to be in a particular format which is really what I am getting at.

I am currently looking for a way to create a new text file that is created by using the values from an ArrayList. How do I create a text file that will allow me to have the format that I am looking for?

Comment: show the code that you tried

Comment: 1. Search on google how to iterate over a List. 2. Search on google how to write to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write an ArrayList of Strings into a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548157/how-to-write-an-arraylist-of-strings-into-a-text-file)

Comment: There are plenty of ways how you can do it, show what you have tried.

Comment: "to have the format that I am looking for" Which format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public static void createTextFileFromArrayList() {

```
    List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
    cities.addAll(Arrays.asList("Boston", "Washington", "Irving", "Dallas"));

    //Get the file reference
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\apps\\output.txt");

    //Use try-with-resource to get auto-closeable writer instance
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
        cities.forEach(city -> {
            try {
                writer.write(city);
                writer.write("\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```